# Linux Tool to create snapshots without downtime

Tags: linux

I remember there was a lightweight filesystem driver that could be put over an existing filesystem to allow the creation of immediate snapshots without downtime, similar as when making a snapshot on a cloud storage.
So you only have to disk-sync your database for a few seconds while executing the command and you'll get a consistent snapshot of that moment.

Though I forgot the name.

(considered LVM, though not sure if it's a good solution for 8TB disks)

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for a copy-on-write filesystem or similar solution. For example:

1. **LVM** you already mentioned,
2. [ZFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZFS), which is a mixture of software RAID, Logical Volume Management and filesystem coming from Solaris,
3. [Btrfs](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page), a younger solution developed for Linux.

They all use the same principle, so they all copy only the modified data.

Comment: ....just to add....physical mirroring, although much less efficient on storage and cost can also be used - just break the mirror and remount the shadow elsewhere.